# Is it possible to debug native C code (an ndk-build project) with Android Studio?

Tags: android, c, arm

I need to debug native C code (ndk-build) on the Android platform.

Is it possible to debug it in Android Studio, and if so how can I do it ?

Comment: I tried to reformulate your post, but it was a bit confusing, if I missed the something, please edit it again to make the question clearer. It's important to try to write in decent english if you want to get answers.

Comment: Even if it is not possible for your IDE to be a front end to the ndk's gdb, it should still be possible to run that independently or with a different front end.  With a little strategic thought, log debugging as suggested in the answers below may indeed be your most direct route to solving a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your C source code, you could add logs with this function:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyTag", "The value is %d", some_variable);
```

Need  this define:

```
#define <android/log.h>
```

Logs will be print in LogCat of Android device.

You don't have "step by step" debugger as in Android application.

Comment: @ranjithkumards Is it useful ?

Answer (score 0):

As the LaurentY response, In your header file, you could define some logs like this:

```
#define <android/log.h>

#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Once in your .c/.cpp code you set the TAG as:

```
#define LOG_TAG "sample.cpp"
```

And call your logs using:

```
LOGI("Yes!!, %s, %s", some, some2);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Connect your device and select it from the dropdown in the "Android" tab view in Studio
3. Go to shell/terminal/CLI and build your app using `ndk-build`, `make` or whatever
4. Set up your usual logcat filters in Studio, and debug away!

Works for me with the lastest Studio version (1.3 RC3). You don't have to debug via CLI / logcat.